# the 2nd gridview is not visible after clicking select button in 1st gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview

i have 2 gridviews. 1st gridview stores the total days worked by the employees in a month and 2nd gridview stores the total hours worked each day by the employee. i have select button in 1st gridview. on clicking that select button, the details of that particular row should display in the 2nd gridview. but after clicking the select button, the 2nd gridview is not visible. how can i achieve this. the code is given below.

```
        protected void gvWorkedDays_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        string someVaribaleName = gvWorkedDays.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text;
        TextBox tb = new TextBox();
        tb.Text = someVaribaleName;            
        dTabPrt = dTable2;
        dTable2 = getConn.GetAdapterDatatable("SELECT tsNo, tsDate, tsOnSite, tsUser, (Select cmName from customermaster where cmCode=tsCustomer), tsCategory, tsDescription, tsFromTime, tsToTime, tsHours, tsExp, (select tmName from taskmaster where tmCode=tsTask), tsStatus, (Select pmName from project where pmCode=tsProject) from timesheet where tsUser='" + tb.Text + "' and tsDate >=  '" + cFDate + "' AND tsdate <=  '" + cTDate + "' GROUP BY tsDate", Global.conStrDatabase);
        gvDetails.DataSource = dTable2;
        gvDetails.DataBind();
        gvDetails.AutoGenerateColumns = true; 
       }
```

i have set the AutoGenerateSelectButton property for 1st gridview as true